# Seeing the tendency of functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, function-and-relation-composition

If $f:[1, 10]\to [1,10]$ is a non decreasing function and $g:[1, 10]\to [1,10]$ is a non increasing function. Let $h(x) =f(g(x)) $ with $h(1)=1$. Then $h(2)$:

$\text{(A)}$ lies in $(1,2)$.

$\text{(B)}$  is  more than 2.

$\text{(C)}$ is equal to $ 1$.

$\text{(D)}$ is not defined.

**My attempt**:

I took the graph of $f(x) $ to be increasing such that it is 2 for $f(1)$ to reach the maximum ordinate of 8 and then I drew the graph of $g(x) $ to be decreasing from $8$ to $1$ then my thought is How $ h(2)$ is going to be equal to $1$ ?!

Comment: Think about it for a minute. If $x \le y$ then $g(x) \ge g(y)$ and so $f(g(x)) \ge f(g(y))$, that is, $h=f \circ g$ is non increasing. If $h(1) = 1$ what does that say about $h$?

Comment: @copper.hat If $h(x)$ is non increasing then maximum value of $h(x)=1$ which will then due to its co-domain and non increasing nature will become constant function. Is that what you wanted to convey?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thanks for making me understand the process.

Comment: Delighted to be able to assist.

Comment: I thought so: I thought it was a constant function h(x) = 1.